# Switch from Apache Prefork MPM to Worker MPM on CentOS 6.3

Tags: apache, worker

So I switched from prefork to worker and now all I am getting is 500 errors when trying to access my site:

HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2013 05:55:08 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Expires: Wed, 16 Apr 2014 05:55:08 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Any idea? What did I miss?

This is what I did:

uncommented HTTPD=/usr/sbin/httpd.worker from /etc/sysconfig/httpd

And installed: yum install php-zts

And just 500 errors, worst thing is, I cant find any logs with any errors...

Answer (score 1):

You should try using FastCGI instead of PHP ZTS to use Apache MPM Worker. As [suggested here](https://newrelic.com/docs/php/php-and-the-apache-worker-mpm):

> there is a way to get the performance benefits of using a threaded MPM and still use PHP: using FastCGI

and, on [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.apache2):

> If you want to use a threaded MPM, look at a FastCGI configuration where PHP is running in its own memory space.